# Wacom intuos issue. Clicking on a App in OS X Dock shows app in finder instead

Tags: macos

I am running Wacom intuos software 6.3.16-12 on OS X El Capitan.     Occasionally, when I click on an App in the OS X dock it will open the finder window and highlight that app, instead of opening the app. It is also happening in various Apps. When I select a Safari bookmark, it will open all Bookmarks in that folder. It's like holding down the command-option key, although I don’t press any keys on my keyboard.

Here’s what I tried:

- I have changed the Wacom pen nib
- In Wacom Preferences I have disabled additional pen shortcuts e.g. right   click…
- In Wacom preferences I’ve changed the Tip feel to »firm«
- I’ve reinstalled the Wacom Driver 2 times.
- Repaired OS X system permissions
- It also happening on another Mac running OS X Yosemite

It’s driving me crazy. What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** I have completely uninstalled Wacom's tablet software *6.3.16-12* and switched back to *6.3.15*-3. Also, be sure to remove all preferences files including the following leftovers:

```
/Volumes/MacBook/Library/Internet/Plug-Ins/WacomTabletPlugin.plugin
/Volumes/MacBook/Library/PreferencePanes/WacomTablet.prefpane
/Volumes/MacBook/Library/Frameworks/WacomMultiTouch.framework
/Volumes/MacBook/System/Library/Extensions/Wacom/Tablet.kext
/Volumes/MacBook/Library/Receipts/Wacom/Tablet/Docs.txt
/Volumes/MacBook/Users/yourusername/Desktop/Preferences.wacomprefs
/Volumes/MacBook/Users/yourusername/Library/Preferences/com.wacom.wacomtouch.prefs
/Volumes/MacBook/Users/yourusername/Library/Preferences/com.wacom.wacomtablet.prefs
/Volumes/MacBook/Library/LaunchAgents/com.wacom.wacomtablet.plist
/Volumes/MacBook/private/var/db/receipts/com.wacom.TabletInstaller.plist
/Volumes/MacBook/private/var/db/receipts/com.wacom.TabletInstaller.bom
/Volumes/MacBook/Users/yourusername/Library/Application/Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ApplicationRecentDocuments/com.wacom.removewacomtablet.sfl
/Volumes/MacBook/Users/yourusername/Library/Saved/Application/State/com.wacom.RemoveWacomTablet.savedState
/Volumes/MacBook/Users/yourusername/Library/Preferences/com.wacom.RemoveWacomTablet.plist
```

I have spent hours on debugging. This issue is definitely related to the Wacom Tablet Software update 6.3.16-12. Morever it’s related to random system crashes and endless error messages in the OS X systemlog.